# Wrong assigning based on a condition in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I am trying to assign "1" for selected columns in df if the value is higher than 100, otherwise "0".

```
vz201408  <- as.numeric(c("0.00","300.00","500.00","0.00","0.00","210","0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201409  <- as.numeric(c("0.00","200.00","200.00","500.00","0.00","500","100","0.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201410 <- as.numeric(c("100","100","100","0.00","0.00","21.00","0.00","0.00","0.00","482"))
vz201411 <- as.numeric(c("0.00","600.00","900.00","100.00","120.00","0.00","50.00","0.00","800.00","664 "))
vz201412 <- as.numeric(c("30.00","40.00","50.00","0.00","9.00","8.00","1.00","4.00","0.00","0.00"))
vz201501 <- as.numeric(c("500.00","100.00","100.00","500.00","0.00","200.00","0.00","0.00","100.00","200.00"))
vz201502 <- as.numeric(c("500.00","100.00","100.00","500.00","0.00","200.00","0.00","0.00","100.00","200.00"))
vz201503 <- as.numeric(c("500.00","100.00","100.00","600.00","0.00","200.00","0.00","0.00","90.00","100.00"))
vz201604 <- as.numeric(c("50.00","10.00","10.00","400.00","100.00","200.00","0.00","0.00","10.00","20.00"))
vz201701 <- as.numeric(c("100.00","10.00","10.00","50.00","0.00","200.00","0.00","300.00","100.00","200.00"))
df <- data.frame(vz201408,vz201409, vz201410, vz201411,vz201412,vz201501,vz201502,vz201503,vz201604,vz201701)
```

I am using this loop but it is wrongly assigning 1/0. It gives "1" even though the value is below the threshold 100. Any suggestions, please? Thank you!

```
# Select only the following columns
col_indices <- grep("^vz2014(1[0-2])$|^vz2015\\d{2}$|^vz2016(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$", names(df))
col_names <- names(df)[col_indices]

for (c in col_names) {
  for (i in 1:length(col_names)) {
    df[, paste0('Empl_vz', i)] <- ifelse(df[, c] >= 100,
                                               1,
                                               0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `c` already represents a column name, why do you then iterate over all columns? Instead, I think we can `seq_along` the names and use a single loop. (Also, you are deriving a logical 0/1, so we can shortcut the conditional and remove `ifelse`.)

FYI, the reason you process is failing is that while it calculates each column correctly, it is overwriting results from the previous iteration in the loop. Notice that all of your columns are the same as the last (correct) column below. Your basic operation wasn't failing, it's just that your loop should have fired exactly `length(col_names)` (5 here) times, instead it was firing `5 * 5` times, and on passes 21-25, it overwrote all columns with that from `col_names[5]`.

```r
col_names <- grep("^vz2014(1[0-2])$|^vz2015\\d{2}$|^vz2016(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$", names(df), value=TRUE)
for (i in seq_along(col_names)) {
  df[, paste0("Empl_vz", i)] <- +(df[, col_names[i]] >= 100)
}
df
#    vz201408 vz201409 vz201410 vz201411 vz201412 vz201501 vz201502 vz201503 vz201604 vz201701 Empl_vz1 Empl_vz2 Empl_vz3 Empl_vz4 Empl_vz5 Empl_vz6 Empl_vz7
# 1         0        0      100        0       30      500      500      500       50      100        1        0        0        1        1        1        0
# 2       300      200      100      600       40      100      100      100       10       10        1        1        0        1        1        1        0
# 3       500      200      100      900       50      100      100      100       10       10        1        1        0        1        1        1        0
# 4         0      500        0      100        0      500      500      600      400       50        0        1        0        1        1        1        1
# 5         0        0        0      120        9        0        0        0      100        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        1
# 6       210      500       21        0        8      200      200      200      200      200        0        0        0        1        1        1        1
# 7         0      100        0       50        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 8         0        0        0        0        4        0        0        0        0      300        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 9         0        0        0      800        0      100      100       90       10      100        0        1        0        1        1        0        0
# 10        0        0      482      664        0      200      200      100       20      200        1        1        0        1        1        1        0
```

A faster way without the loop:

```r
df[, paste0("Empl_vz", seq_along(col_names))] <- +(df[, col_names] >= 100)
df
#    vz201408 vz201409 vz201410 vz201411 vz201412 vz201501 vz201502 vz201503 vz201604 vz201701 Empl_vz1 Empl_vz2 Empl_vz3 Empl_vz4 Empl_vz5 Empl_vz6 Empl_vz7
# 1         0        0      100        0       30      500      500      500       50      100        1        0        0        1        1        1        0
# 2       300      200      100      600       40      100      100      100       10       10        1        1        0        1        1        1        0
# 3       500      200      100      900       50      100      100      100       10       10        1        1        0        1        1        1        0
# 4         0      500        0      100        0      500      500      600      400       50        0        1        0        1        1        1        1
# 5         0        0        0      120        9        0        0        0      100        0        0        1        0        0        0        0        1
# 6       210      500       21        0        8      200      200      200      200      200        0        0        0        1        1        1        1
# 7         0      100        0       50        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 8         0        0        0        0        4        0        0        0        0      300        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# 9         0        0        0      800        0      100      100       90       10      100        0        1        0        1        1        0        0
# 10        0        0      482      664        0      200      200      100       20      200        1        1        0        1        1        1        0
```

The reason that `+(.)` works is through R's coersion from class-to-class. You can do basic math on logicals (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) because R converts it into `1`/`0`. The simplest math operation is the unary `+` before a number or expression. (Try `+TRUE` and `+FALSE` to confirm.)

Comment: Very good elaboration on how to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but maybe you want to output a data frame with the dimensions of the original data frame. Using an `if`/`else` conditional to identify the desired columns.

```
cols <- grep("^vz2014(1[0-2])$|^vz2015\\d{2}$|^vz2016(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$", names(df))

df_new <- setNames(data.frame(sapply(seq_along(df), function(x)
  if(any(x == cols)){(df[,x] > 100) * 1} else{df[,x]})), colnames(df))

colnames(df_new)[cols] <- paste0("Empl_vz", 1:length(cols))

df_new
   vz201408 vz201409 Empl_vz1 Empl_vz2 Empl_vz3 Empl_vz4 Empl_vz5 Empl_vz6
1         0        0        0        0        0        1        1        1
2       300      200        0        1        0        0        0        0
3       500      200        0        1        0        0        0        0
4         0      500        0        0        0        1        1        1
5         0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
6       210      500        0        0        0        1        1        1
7         0      100        0        0        0        0        0        0
8         0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
9         0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
10        0        0        1        1        0        1        1        0
   Empl_vz7 vz201701
1         0      100
2         0       10
3         0       10
4         1       50
5         0        0
6         1      200
7         0        0
8         0      300
9         0      100
10        0      200
```